# SVN : 500 internal server error on my repository access

Tags: svn, ubuntu, repository

(OS is Ubuntu Server)

I create a new repository with SVN like that :

```
$ svnadmin create myrepo --pre-1.6-compatible
```

The first time, when I want to access in my new repository **myrepo** (with TortoiseSVN tool), I could reach in reading, but in writing, I couldn't (lock SVN message appears). So I found on forum post, a guy who recommanded to set all rights on repository like that :

```
$ chmod -r 770 myrootrepositories
```

And after that, I can't access to **all** my repositories ... with TortoiseSVN, this error appears when I want to access to a repository :

```
Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request for https://xx.xx.xx.xx/svn/myrepo
```

I restart all, but nothing changed...

Answer (score 2):

**ERROR:**

> svn: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request for

**CAUSE:** The user's file (or some other file in the project SVN directory), was created using the root account and it has to be owned by the domain account.

**Example:** domain user is `trespatitos` (using CPANEL/WHM and Centos 5), so I used:

```
root@myserver [my project path]# chown -R trespatitos:trespatitos ./*
```

That changes the owner and group recursively on the dir I'm standing at.

Also. On the `svn.conf` file, I have:

```
AuthUserFile /home/myusername/svn/hds/conf/.svn-users
```

While in the SVN folder I made a mistake and name the file: `.users-svn`

I changed the name and the problem was solved.

Conclusion:

- Check Ownership
- Check Permissions 775 or 777 of the SVN dir.
- Check that the users file actually exists. If it doesn't, use `htpasswd -c username .svn-users`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the repositories have the 'group'. Set it to the same as the group as the webserver:

```
sudo chown -R :www-data myrootrepositories
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed it for me. Key was the -R, also set the owner to the webserver user (eg. `sudo chown -R www:www myrepo`)

Answer (score 0):

Set the ownership of the repository to the same user that runs svnserve.

Answer (score 0):

The real cause is an unreadable config file, it can be found on the Cpanel raw error log.

In my case, I was following instructions for an old repo, the file name I used was .users-conf, then I was trying to access .svn-users, the error was logged in the error log.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into the same problem.  Permissions and other items mentioned were OK.  But the timestamps on the files were wrong (because copied from an older working copy when needing to change a repository).  Just touched everything.