# Missing information while migrating SVN repo from one server to another

Tags: svn, apache2, ubuntu-12.04

I want to migrate data from old SVN server to new server. I need a SVN location with 2 folders trunk and branch. I also want to be able to add new folders at a later point in time so that i can just move the source code to new branches. So i followed the steps at [link](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-use-svn-with-apache-dav_svn-on-ubuntu-14.04) though my ubuntu is 12.04. The steps i tried are as follows from my user home:

```
mkdir /home/user/svn
cd /home/user/svn
sudo mkdirs trunk branch
sudo svnadmin create trunk
sudo svnadmin create branch
sudo svnadmin --force-uuid load /home/user/svn/trunk < /home/user/sample.svn_dump
```

My `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf` looks like:

```
 <Location /svn>             
      DAV svn     
      SVNParentPath /home/user/svn    
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Subversion Repository"
      AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd    
      Require valid-user    
    </Location>
```

After successful loading the data when i access http://{ip}/svn/trunk i see `Internal Server Error`

Can anyone suggest on this i am new to SVNadmin and configurations.

Error logs from apache2 logs:

```
[notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
[error] [client 192.168.7.83] Could not fetch resource information.  [403, #0]
[error] [client 192.168.7.83] (2)No such file or directory: The URI does not contain the name of a repository.  [403$
[error] [client 192.168.7.83] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to access /home/user/svn/trunk locally with file: protocol

Something like this:

```
svn ls file:///home/user/svn/trunk
```

Possible it show more clear error message.

Comment: I see the follow error: 
`svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///home/user/svn'` i also see somehow `home` is getting resolved to home + current user like `/home/user`

Comment: Did you use file:///home/user/svn or file:///home/user/svn/trunk ? Second one is correct. Also I suspect you can misunderstud svn conception due to unusual repository names - *trunk* and *branch*. Are yoy sure it should be different repositories? Usaully it is different branches in same repository.

Comment: Corrected the path now i see the folders. Now what i should be doing? Actually i want something like branch_V1, branch_V2, etc., as i have more and more releases so that the most current is in trunk. You are right that branch and trunk should be in same repositories but i was unable to create it so i choose it to be in different repos.

Comment: Well, if you can access to repository with svn, then it is time to look in Apache logs (may be it will require enable verbose logging). I don't know how to doing it exactly, use google/bing/whatsever..

Comment: I think it should be error.log or something like this. access.log sounds for me like log of successfull requests.

Comment: I see the error when i try to checkout `svn: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request` does it make sense?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030453/svn-500-internal-server-error-on-my-repository-access
Possible problems with user access?

Comment: Checking the error.log helped me. Now am able to view it in the browsers but for some reason i am unable to access it through a remote client/browser. Any suggestion please?

Comment: What the error show browser/svn when you try access it remotely?